# Why doesn't Synth.new understand about scales?

Tags: supercollider

I can set a scale like this:

```
~pp = Scale.phrygian(\pythagorean);
```

I can then create a `Pbind` which plays the scale like this:

```
(
Pbind(
    *[
        instrument: \default,
        scale: ~pp,
        degree: Pseq([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], inf),
        amp: 0.5,
        dur: 0.5
    ]
).play;
)
```

But `Synth.new` doesn't seem to get it at all (just results in silence):

```
b = Synth.new(\default, [\scale: ~pp, \degree: 3, \amp, 0.5]);
```

Interestingly, if I remove the `scale` parameter:

```
b = Synth.new(\default, [\degree: 3, \amp, 0.5]);
```

then I get a note, but it's always *the same* note. It doesn't respond to the `degree` parameter.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to trigger notes from an external OSC device (my phone!). This means hooking up `OSCFunc` to listen out for certain triggers, and play notes from a scale when those OSC events occur. I thought I could use `Synth.new` inside `OSCFunc` to actually play the notes, but it doesn't seem to know about scales, so I'm a bit stuck.

Can anyone provide any advice about how to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a good read of the Pattern Guide, in particular [Pattern Guide 07: Value Conversions](http://doc.sccode.org/Tutorials/A-Practical-Guide/PG_07_Value_Conversions.html). It's a good tutorial. It will tell you that these magical conversions are not used everywhere in SuperCollider, but only when you use `Event`-based scheduling such as Patterns (e.g. your `Pbind`). The value conversions are actually defined in "the default Event", as described further in that tutorial article.

One consequence of all of this is that, if you want to launch *just one* note but you still want value conversions, you can do it with the Event style of playing notes, which creates an event using `()` and then calls `.play` on it:

```
  ~synth = (instrument: \default, scale: [0,2,4,5,7,9,11], degree: 12.rand, amp: 0.5).play;

  ~synth = (instrument: \default, scale: [0,3,6,9], degree: 12.rand, amp: 0.5).play;
```

This still returns a Synth object.
See [the Event helpfile](http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/Event.html) for more on this way of doing it.

Comment: Oh my days. Thank you once again.